# How to access node in the firebase databse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

My aim is to have each user select a total of 6 players. when each player is selected, the player id is sent to a node on the database called 'total'using the push () method. The code is written below

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('players');

var ref3 =  firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(uid).child('total');

$scope.players = $firebaseArray(ref);

console.log ($scope.players); 


 $scope.history = [];

 $scope.buy = function(player) {
    //remove if already added locally
    var index = $scope.history.indexOf(player);
    if(index>=0){
        $scope.history.splice(index,1);
        return;
    }

    //remove if already added on firebase 


    //max 6 allowed
    if($scope.history.length>=6){
        alert('max 6 allowed');
        return;
    }

    var selected = $scope.history.reduce(function(a,b){
        a[b.position] = (a[b.position] || 0) + 1;
        return a;
    }, {}) || {};

    if(!selected[player.position] || selected[player.position]<2){
        $scope.history.push(player);
        ref3.push(player.id);
    }else{
        alert('You can add only two players per position');
    }
     };

     $scope.getTotal = function(){
    return $scope.history.reduce(function(tot, p){
        tot = tot - p.price;
        return tot;
    }, $scope.total);
     };
```

this is how the database is structured :

```
   {
    "players" : [ {
      "R" : 0,
    "Team" : "Industry",
   "Y" : 0,
     "assists" : 0,
     "goals" : 0,
  "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Yasin 'YB' Amusan",
   "position" : "forward",
   "price" : 8000000
     }, {
    "R" : 0,
    "Team" : "Industry",
     "Y" : 0,
   "assists" : 0,
    "goals" : 0,
   "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Hassan 'Hasi' Akinyera",
    "position" : "defender",
     "price" : 5000000
     }],

   "users" : {
 "l3J1TVsFNLMi0Oxg6hz4AJpacE53" : {
  "email" : "awoniyideji@yahoo.com",
  "fullname" : "Djflex11",
  "teamname" : "deji awoniyi",
  "total" : {
    "-Kpl19z_25IEhiCEFrui" : 1,
    "-Kpl1ARqT-v_btJ7OAq2" : 2,
    "-Kpl1AsdodYWVPWWd5xA" : 2,
    "-Kpl1iN7a7PLU-tnkKc4" : 1,
    "-Kpl1j5CtN6c_mnmWLP-" : 1,
    "-Kpl1k0BNCP5NNFV5uX6" : 1
    },
    "userName" : "awoniyideji@yahoo.com",
    "week" : "no", 
     }
     }
     }
```

My ISSUE

The aim is that a player cannot be selected twice by the same user. MY code currently prevents a player from being selected twice locally, but the same player id can be pushed to the firebase database. My issue is how to basically check the total node so that the selected player if already "pushed" into database, will be removed instead of inserted into the database. I know that 'indexOf' is to be avoided with firebase.

Comment: I suggest you take more care of the indentation. Cleaner code is better to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if(ref3.toJSON().hasOwnProperty(playerId)){
  ref3.child(playerId).remove();
}
```

References:

[Check for key in JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

[Remove from DB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176754/jorge-bar-mza this did not work. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the unique ids generated by the push () method cannot be accessed and so distorts the database path?